Why is my Signal Store in Angular not working?
i have a problem with my signal store to modify my shoppinglist, so i have a problem to add a new shoppinglist to my signalstore:
import { Product } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/Product';
import {
  patchState,
  signalStore,
  withComputed, withHooks,
  withMethods,
  withState
} from '@ngrx/signals';
import { ShoppingList } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingList';
import { HttpShoppingListService } from '../service/http-shopping-list.service';
import { computed, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { rxMethod } from '@ngrx/signals/rxjs-interop';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, pipe, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { tapResponse } from '@ngrx/operators';
import { ShoppingListToCreate } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingListToCreate';
import { ShoppingListToUpdate } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingListToUpdate';

type Filter = {
  shoppingListId: string;
  order: 'asc' | 'desc';
};

type ShoppingListState = {
  shoppingLists: ShoppingList[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  filter: Filter;
};

const initialState: ShoppingListState = {
  shoppingLists: [],
  isLoading: false,
  filter: { shoppingListId: '', order: 'asc' },
};

export const ShoppingListStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState(initialState),
  withComputed(({ shoppingLists, filter }) => ({
    shoppingListCount: computed(() => shoppingLists().length),
    sortedShoppingLists: computed(() => {
      const direction = filter().order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
      const test =  [...shoppingLists()].sort(
        (a, b) => direction * a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      );
      console.log(test)
      return test
    }),
    findShoppingListById: computed(() => {
      return shoppingLists().filter(
          (entry: ShoppingList) => entry.id === filter().shoppingListId
        );
    }),
  })),
  withMethods((store, httpShoppingListService = inject(HttpShoppingListService)) => ({
      loadShoppingListsByGroupId: rxMethod<string>(
        pipe(
          debounceTime(300),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          switchMap((groupId: string) =>
            httpShoppingListService.getAllShoppingLists(groupId).pipe(
              tapResponse({
                next: (shoppingLists: ShoppingList[]) =>
                  patchState(store, { shoppingLists }),
                error: (err) => {
                  console.error(err);
                },
                finalize: () => patchState(store, { isLoading: false }),
              })
            )
          )
        )
      ),

      addShoppingList: rxMethod<{ shoppingListToCreate: ShoppingListToCreate }>(
        pipe(
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          switchMap(({ shoppingListToCreate }) =>
            httpShoppingListService.addShoppingList(shoppingListToCreate).pipe(
              tapResponse({
                next: (createdShoppingList: ShoppingList) => {
                  patchState(store, {
                    shoppingLists: [
                      ...store.sortedShoppingLists(),
                      createdShoppingList,
                    ],
                  });
                },
                error: (err) => console.error(err),
                finalize: () => patchState(store, { isLoading: false }),
              })
            )
          )
        )
      ),

      addProductsToShoppingList: rxMethod<{
        shoppingListId: string;
        products: Product[];
      }>(
        pipe(
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          switchMap(({ shoppingListId, products }) =>
            httpShoppingListService
              .addProductsToShoppingList(shoppingListId, products)
              .pipe(
                tapResponse({
                  next: (updatedShoppingList: ShoppingList) => {
                    patchState(store, ({ shoppingLists }) => ({
                      shoppingLists: shoppingLists.map((list) =>
                        list.id === shoppingListId ? updatedShoppingList : list
                      ),
                    }));
                  },
                  error: (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                  },
                  finalize: () => patchState(store, { isLoading: false }),
                })
              )
          )
        )
      ),

      updateShoppingList: rxMethod<{
        shoppingListToUpdate: ShoppingListToUpdate;
      }>(
        pipe(
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          tap(() => patchState(store, { isLoading: true })),
          switchMap(({ shoppingListToUpdate }) =>
            httpShoppingListService
              .updateShoppingList(shoppingListToUpdate)
              .pipe(
                tapResponse({
                  next: (updatedShoppingList: ShoppingList) => {
                    patchState(store, ({ shoppingLists }) => ({
                      shoppingLists: shoppingLists.map((list) =>
                        list.id === shoppingListToUpdate.id
                          ? updatedShoppingList
                          : list
                      ),
                    }));
                  },
                  error: (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                  },
                  finalize: () => patchState(store, { isLoading: false }),
                })
              )
          )
        )
      ),
    })
  ),
  withHooks({
    onInit(store) {
      store.loadShoppingListsByGroupId('1');
    },
  }),
);

my http service is mocked and have no connections to a backend:
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ShoppingList } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingList';
import { Product } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/Product';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ShoppingListToCreate } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingListToCreate';
// @ts-ignore
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { ShoppingListToUpdate } from '../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingListToUpdate';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpShoppingListService {
  private readonly httpClient = inject(HttpClient);
  private tempoaery: ShoppingList[] = [
    { id: '1', name: 'a', groupId: '1', products: [] },
  ];

  getAllShoppingLists(groupId: string): Observable<ShoppingList[]> {
    return of(this.tempoaery);
  }

  addProductsToShoppingList(
    shoppingListId: string,
    products: Product[]
  ): Observable<ShoppingList> {
    const shoppingList: ShoppingList = this.tempoaery.filter(
      (shoppingList) => shoppingList.id === shoppingListId
    )[0];
    shoppingList.products.push(...products);
    return of(shoppingList);
  }

  addShoppingList(
    shoppingListToCreate: ShoppingListToCreate
  ): Observable<ShoppingList> {
    const shoppingList: ShoppingList = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: shoppingListToCreate.name,
      groupId: shoppingListToCreate.groupId,
      products: [],
    };
    this.tempoaery.push(shoppingList)
    return of(shoppingList);
  }

  updateShoppingList(
    shoppingListToUpdate: ShoppingListToUpdate
  ): Observable<ShoppingList> {
    this.tempoaery.map((list) =>
      list.id === shoppingListToUpdate.id ? shoppingListToUpdate : list
    );
    return of(shoppingListToUpdate as ShoppingList);
  }
}

SO Adding products to the one entity works perfect but why cant i adding a new shoppinglist. when im debuging with console.log i can see that the store have a new array of the entity... but my compontent still load one shoppinglist:
import { Component, computed, effect, inject, OnInit, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingListStore } from '../../store/shoppingListStore';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { ShoppingListFormComponent } from '../shopping-list-form/shopping-list-form.component';
import { ShoppingList } from '../../../../../../shared/src/lib/ShoppingList';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-list',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [JsonPipe, ShoppingListFormComponent],
  templateUrl: './group-list.component.html',
  providers: [ShoppingListStore],
  styleUrl: './group-list.component.scss',
})
export class GroupListComponent implements OnInit {
  protected readonly shoppingListStore = inject(ShoppingListStore);
  shoppingLists: Signal<ShoppingList[]> = this.shoppingListStore.sortedShoppingLists;
  readonly isLoading = this.shoppingListStore.isLoading;
  readonly count: Signal<number> = this.shoppingListStore.shoppingListCount;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shoppingLists = this.shoppingListStore.sortedShoppingLists
  }

}

<!--@let count = this.shoppingListStore.shoppingListCount();-->
<!--@let shoppingLists = this.shoppingListStore.sortedShoppingLists();-->
<div>test: {{isLoading()|json}}</div>
<!--@defer(when !isLoading()) {-->
<!--@if(shoppingLists ? shoppingLists() : []) {-->
  <div>
    <span>Shoppinglists:</span>
    {{ shoppingLists() | json }}
  </div>
  <div>a:{{ count() | json }}</div>
<!--}-->

<!--}-->

<br>

-----------
<br>

have anybody a idea ?

The problem is still not resolved. Can anybody help me?
